# Performing inference across multiple target variables with Gaussian Processes regression

Tags: regression, gaussian-process, kriging

Suppose I have a design matrix $\mathbf{X}$ with targets $\mathbf{y}_1$, when plotted looks like so:

[image]

the data is very sparse, and the magnitude of the targets is shown by color bar, where each training point in the design matrix is 2D.

Now in my problem setup I in fact have five sets of target variables $\{\mathbf{y}_1,\mathbf{y}_2,\mathbf{y}_3,\mathbf{y}_4,\mathbf{y}_5\}$ - each with the *same* design matrix $\mathbf{X}$. But I am performing learning and inference separately and independently for each target, but they are all in fact related. But are currently not being treated as such.

It must be the case that sharing information during learning and inference, should yield a better posterior predictive estimate. I.e. jointly performing regression across all five targets.

I was wondering if someone could shed light on how one performs this type of GPR where there are multiple, related/dependent, targets?

**EDIT:**

It would appear that this falls within the dominion of co-kriging.

Comment: I'm going off of the definitions of design matrix and target from the Rassmussen Williams book, chapter 2.  If I am not mistaken, you can do this by averaging the target variables and then perform inference with the noise $\sigma^2_n$ decreased appropriately to reflect your increased certainty in the value of the target variable.

Comment: @StefanJorgensen precisely this is using Rasmussen's notation. Ok but if I am trying to learn the non-linear mapping between the training inputs and the targets, jointly, how would one proceed if we first average over the target variables. Or rather what might we expect the effect to be?

Comment: Just to clarify what you mean from a functional perspective: do you mean that you have five functions, and $y_1 = f_1(X) + \epsilon_1$, $y_2 = f_2(X) + \epsilon_2$, etc., or that you have a five "measurements" of the same function at the same locations, e.g. $y_1 = f(X) + \epsilon_1$, $y_2 = f(X) + \epsilon_2$ etc. ?

Comment: Let me clarify; I want to learn five separate functions that take the same input $X$ such that $\mathbf{y}_1 = f_1(X)$, $\mathbf{y}_2 = f_2(X)$ etc. So the design matrix remains the same, but the functions map to different domains, each represented via a target.

Comment: In that case, there is not necessarily any value to performing joint regression. Consider a simple case where $f_1$ depends on the first component of each coordinate in $X$, but $f_2$ depends only on the second component. In my first comment I thought you meant the case where there is a single function $f$.  I don't know much about it, but multi-output GPR sounds more like what you are looking for.

Comment: Oh I see, regrettably no, there are several functions, each which play a different role but are related to all the other functions. I'll checkout multi-output GPR. Thanks.